# How can I add objects to a scene from an array one at a time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, swift

I have an array with 30 SKSpriteNodes.  I'd like to add each node to the scene one at a time, with a small time delay.  This is what I have so far, but it adds all the sprites instantaneously.

```
   for var i = 0; i < 31; i++ {

        var boardPiece = SKShapeNode()
        boardPiece = addBigRedCircle()
        redPiecesArray.addObject(boardPiece)
        self.addChild(redPiecesArray.objectAtIndex(i) as SKNode)

        }
```

How could I add these objects from the array 1 at a time and so efficiently?  (If you know how to do this with Obj-C, that would help to as I can probably figure out how to say the same thing with Swift)

Answer (score 0):

How about using GCD? Is that a thing in Swift?

```
for var i = 0; i < 31; i++ {
  dispatch_after((Int64)(i * delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {     
    var boardPiece = SKShapeNode()
    boardPiece = addBigRedCircle()
    redPiecesArray.addObject(boardPiece)
    self.addChild(redPiecesArray.objectAtIndex(i) as SKNode)
  })
}
```

(Structure of `dispatch_after` modified based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034838/2708650 )

Comment: I'm still really new to Swift and Obj-C.  I looked it up and GCD with Swift is definitely do-able.  I just don't understand GCD unfortunately.http://fruitstandsoftware.com/blog/2014/06/09/gcd-in-swift-it-just-works/

Comment: Did you try just running the code I wrote there? It looks like those functions should still exist with that API in Swift. I don't develop in Swift, so I don't have a sandbox I could test it in.

Comment: Yea, I tried pasting your code.  But Swift doesn't seem to have int64_t but it does have Int64.  So when I tried Int64 I get the error "Cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '(dispatch_time_t, dispatch_queue_t!, () -> () -> $T15)'